# Using capacitive coupling to implement pulse transition

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I was reading about master-slave flip flops, used to implement edge triggering and I read that instead of using master slave configurations, using RC coupling to clock inputs could also enable pulse transition. How is this possible?

Comment: What is "pulse transition"? Do you have a link to the article you read?

Comment: I was reading "sequential circuits" from Digital Logic and Computer Design-Morris and Mano. Unfortunately I don't have link, it's a hard text book....sorry

Comment: I think by pulse transition they mean the edge triggering pulses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague — can you provide a specific example?

But in any case, the general concept is that an RC high-pass filter will convert a rising edge into a narrow positive pulse and a falling edge into a negative pulse. The negative pulses can be inverted to create a second set of positive pulses that's offset in time. Essentially, you end up creating  a "local" 2-phase pulse-type clock out of the original single-phase square-wave clock.

In older logic technologies (think vacuum tubes), it was possible to "tune" the pulse widths so that data would propagate through just one flip-flop during one pulse duration, so multi-phase clocks were not necessary. However, as systems became larger and more complex, and we moved on to newer technologies (solid state) whose characteristics were less well-controlled, this approach had to be abandoned as unworkable. Multi-phase clocks became common (up through the first generation of IC microprocessors), and eventually, we switched entirely to master-slave flip-flops, which allowed us to migrate to single-phase square-wave clocks, simplifying clock generation and distribution.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. Yes, I understand, if my RC time constant is not very high, I can turn a step signal into a sort of pulse, not exactly squarish, but yes a pulse. Thank you...:)